# Using jasmine to test angular directive that uses a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a jasmine test that will test if an angular directive I've written is working.

Here is my spec file:

```
    describe('blurb directive', function () {
    var scope, httpMock, element, controller;

    beforeEach(module('mdotTamcCouncil'));
    beforeEach(module('mdotTamcCouncil.core'));
    beforeEach(module('blurb'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $compile) {
        element = angular.element('<mcgi-blurb text-key="mainPageIntro"></mcgi-blurb>');

        var httpResponse = '<textarea name="content" ng-model="content"></textarea>';

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        httpMock = _$httpBackend_;

        httpMock.whenGET('components/blurb/blurb.html').respond(httpResponse);
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should have some content', function () {
        expect(scope.content).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The value "scope.content" is always undefined and when I look at the scope object it seems to be a generic scope object that doesn't have my custom attributes on it.

Here are the other related files:

*blurb-directive.js*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('blurb')
        .directive('mcgiBlurb', blurb);

    function blurb() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: jsGlobals.componentsFolder + '/blurb/blurb.html',
            controller: 'BlurbController',
            controllerAs: 'blurb',
            bindToController: false,
            scope: {
                textKey: "@"
            }

        };

    };
})();
```

*blurb-controller.js*

```
(function () {

    angular.module('blurb')
            .controller('BlurbController', ['$scope', 'blurbsFactory', 'userFactory', function ($scope, blurbsFactory, userFactory) {
                $scope.content = "";
                $scope.blurbs = {};
                $scope.currentUser = {};
                this.editMode = false;


                userFactory().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.currentUser = data;
                });

                blurbsFactory().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.blurbs = data;
                    $scope.content = $scope.blurbs[$scope.textKey];
                });

                this.enterEditMode = function () {
                    this.editMode = true;
                };

                this.saveEdits = function () {
                    this.editMode = false;
                    $scope.blurbs[$scope.textKey] = $scope.content;
                };
            }]);

})();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive has isolated scope, so the scope passed to its controller and link function (if there was one), is the isolated one, different than your `scope`.

You *may* have luck getting the scope of the directive using `element.isolateScope()`; you may not, because of the `replace: true` - try to make sure. You may also access the controller instance using `element.controller('mcgiBlurb')`.

Comment: I tried setting scope=element.isolateScope() but that is undefined.  Also, element.controller() appears to be undefined as well.  Ideas?

Comment: I *guess* it is because of the `replace: true`. Could you try using `false` and also try calling `isolatedScope()` *and* `scope()` on the *child* element of `<mcgi-blurb>` - it should be the `<textarea>`? Also, launch Karma in continous mode and try debugging - Batarang or [angscope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) may come in handy.

Comment: By the way, it should be `.controller('mcgiBlurb')`!

Comment: I figured out it's a combination of what you suggested and the fact that I was using "templateUrl" in my directive.  I changed it from using "templateUrl" to "template" and using isolateScope and it now displays the default value that I'm trying to check.  I guess I have to get my karma setup to handle templates.